# How to use delegate token for storefront API Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api-node, shopify-storefront-api

I made a node application based on storefront API of shopify. However there are rate limit per ip address imposed. Due to this I can execute certain Graphql queries a set amount of time. For example, password reset only works 2 times and after that it show Limit Exceeded error, after which I need to wait for 60 seconds.
The issue is I have deployed application as lambda function and the IP will always be the same. I found the solution on storefront API stating I need to use delegate token and user IP to as header while sending the request. But I did not quite understand.

**Can someone please help me how should I use delegate token in my node application, so that the whenever a request is sent it uses the client browser IP instead of the AWS server!**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, believe I figured it out.

First thing you to do is create a delegate token using this endpoint (POST).
`https://{{shopify_store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/access_tokens/delegate.json`

Your POST should look something like this:

```
{
  "delegate_access_scope": ["unauthenticated_write_checkouts"]
}
```

I suggest you go into your shopify store front API and view which permissions the storefront API has and use something similar. Note that your admin API needs to at least have those permissions to grant them.

Also note that the customerRecover needs the "unauthenticated_write_checkouts" permission to be called.

After you created that token (And this was the problem I had) REMOVE the `X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token` from your header, and REPLACE it with  `Shopify-Storefront-Private-Token`

Remove:

`X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token : {{{Storefront Token}}}`

and Replace with:

`Shopify-Storefront-Private-Token : {{{Your delegate token}}}`

You will also need to forward your customers API address in the header by grabbing it out of the context and putting into the header as well

`Shopify-Storefront-Buyer-IP' : this.sourceIp`

After I did this, I noticed my rate limiting on forgot password was IP based on the client hitting it and not the servers IP being throttled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I'm getting a `[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)` error even though I've validated that it is the right Key. I've tried both the API Key and Access Token for the private app.

Comment: I opened a new issue for it here, if you have any insights, I'd appreciate it as I'm going crazy :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527788/shopify-storefront-api-error-delegate-access-token