# Shopify Storefront API error Delegate Access Token

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I've made progress (I think) with getting delegate access scope working on my custom app for my store. However, I keep getting this error:

> Error: GraphQL Error (Code: 422):
> {"response":{"errors":{"delegate_access_scope":["The access scope
> can't be empty."]},

To simply get this working I'm using the example from the docs:

```
const accessToken = gql`mutation {
    delegateAccessTokenCreate(input: { delegateAccessScope: ["write_orders" ], expiresIn: 3600 }){
      delegateAccessToken {
        accessToken
      }
      shop {
        id
      }
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
    }
  }`
```

I'm kind of at my wits end here as I finally realized that the delegate.json actually needs the ADMIN key rather than the storefront even though I want to use this with the storefront API (which is weird). All I want to be able to do is create a new customer with a password via this API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to change delegateAccessScope:  to  delegate_access_scope per doc, https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/delegate-access-tokens/create

{
"delegate_access_scope": [
"write_orders"
],
"expires_in": 3600
}

Comment: This is a valid suggestion given the error likewise printed it out that way. I'll note that I took this GraphQL from the docs. However, I did make that change and it results in a similar error:

`Error: GraphQL Error (Code: 422): {"response":{"errors":{"delegate_access_scope":["The access scope can't be empty."]},`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out. I don't actually want a delegateAccessToken to create a user but to have a Storefront API Access Token. This may get a bit confusing but you use your Admin Access Token to request a storefront access token like so (I use graphql-request on npm):

```
 const accessToken = gql`mutation storefrontAccessTokenCreate($input: StorefrontAccessTokenInput!) {
    storefrontAccessTokenCreate(input: $input) {
      shop {
        id
      }
      storefrontAccessToken {
        accessToken
      }
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
    }
  }`

  const accessTokenVars = {
    "input": {
      "title": "my-access-token"
    }
  }

  const queryAccessTokenData = await adminGraphQLClient.request(accessToken, accessTokenVars);
```

From here you now have a Storefront Access Token and can make a call via Oauth to create a customer like so:

```
const shopifyUserQuery = gql`mutation customerCreate($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
    customerCreate(input: $input) {
      customer {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        acceptsMarketing
      }
      customerUserErrors {
        field
        message
        code
      }
    }
  }`

  const shopifyUserVars = 
  {
    "input": {
      "firstName": values.firstName,
      "lastName": values.lastName,
      "email": values.email,
      "password": values.password,
      "acceptsMarketing": false,
    }
  }

  // We need to switch the default storefront headers over to our private API key
  sfGraphQLClient.headers = {
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': queryAccessTokenData.storefrontAccessTokenCreate.storefrontAccessToken.accessToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  const shopifyCreateCustData = await sfGraphQLClient.request(shopifyUserQuery, shopifyUserVars);
```

This will now create the user using the Storefront API.